# Pandas to_csv with quoting=3 (QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

From [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) regarding `to_csv()` and others:

> quoting : int, Controls whether quotes should be recognized. Values are taken from csv.QUOTE_* values. Acceptable values are 0, 1, 2, and 3 for QUOTE_MINIMAL, QUOTE_ALL, QUOTE_NONE, and QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, respectively.

Setting `quoting=3` still does not quote strings even if they're not numeric, and `libreoffice` is constantly defaulting to splitting by spaces which I never realise until its too late. How can I write CSV, quoting strings with spaces correctly?

Answer (score 29):

It seems like the value in the [`csv` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) has changed since these docs were written. Rather than use the magic number `3`, use `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` to be safe...

```
>>> import csv
>>> csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
2
```

In full:

```
table.to_csv("myfile.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Error thrown is: NameError: name 'csv' is not defined

Comment: `import csv` first, @geekidharsh