# Converting a dataframe column explicitly to text format and cannot be inferred as a number in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a Dataframe with an ID column. This column is usually a 8-digit number. When I write this dataframe to a CSV file, is then uploaded and processed by an external application, reading the ID column as a string.

A problem occurs where the column type is misinterpreted in the external application to be a number instead of text. To get around this issue, I have to open the CSV file manually in my choice of application (Libre office Calc) and go Data -> "Text to Columns" and set the column type to be Text. Uploading the file manually after doing this gets around the issue. I've tried setting the column type in my code:

```
dataframe_df['id'] = dataframe_df['id'].astype(str)
```

but this does not stop the error from occurring. Is there some step I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you post samples of those CSV's? (generated by pandas and generated by Libre)

Comment: I'd use `quoting` parameter: `df.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv', quoting=2)` assuming that `id` column is of string (object) dtype

Comment: It may be preferable to use the more verbose `import csv; df.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)`, especially since the value 2 is subject to change (at one point it was 3, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28541303/5496433)).

Comment: @BallpointBen, good point, thank you! Actually the second Python ZEN rule says: `Explicit is better than implicit.`. Shame on me... ;)